# Selenium is not finding the element/table even if it on screen

Tags: python, selenium

So guys, I'm trying automating downloading documents on a platform.
The problem is: Selenium is not finding the list of available documents.

I can click on the sidebar to charge the table, I put a long timeout timer on the wait, and even though the table is loaded and on screen, selenium won't find it. This is the code:

```
VeiculosBtn = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ext-gen43"]/li[2]/div/a/span')))
VeiculosBtn.click()

time.sleep(1)
aReceberBtn = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ext-gen45"]/li[1]/div/a/span')))
aReceberBtn.click()

time.sleep(10)

table_exist = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table")))
```

The first clicks are to select the option that loads the table on the sidebar, and then is supposed to be identifying/interacting with the table. but then it halts at identifying that the element is there.

can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: Without a link to the actual website (aka the source code) your question is unanswerable.

Comment: If your able to click other elements on the page and not the table. Check if the table is under any iframes or shadow root. If you are getting a NosuchElement error this is most likely the case.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan yeah, it is inside an Iframe...is there a workaround that makes it possible to work/search inside it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below would work for iframes.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"")))
```

Or

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name(''))
```